# Deleting xml file using radio value

Tags: php, html, xml

i using php to delete file, but i got table loop like this:

```
    <table border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="product-table">
                <tr class="bg_tableheader">
                    <th class="table-header-check"><a id="toggle-all" ></a> </th>
                    <th class="table-header-check"><a href="#"><font color="white">Username</font></a>  </th>
                    <th class="table-header-check"><a href="#"><font color="white">First Name</font></a></th>
                    <th class="table-header-check"><a href="#"><font color="white">Last Name</font></a></th>
                    <th class="table-header-check"><a href="#"><font color="white">Email</font></a></th>
                    <th class="table-header-check"><a href="#"><font color="white">Group</font></a></th>
                    <th class="table-header-check"><a href="#"><font color="white">Birthday</font></a></th>
                    <th class="table-header-check"><a href="#"><font color="white">Gender</font></a></th>
                    <th class="table-header-check"><a href="#"><font color="white">Age</font></a></th>
                    <th class="table-header-check"><a href="#"><font color="white">Country</font></a></th>
                </tr>
                <?php
        $files = glob('users/*.xml');
        foreach($files as $file){
            $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($file, 0, true);
            echo '
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <form action="" method="post">
                    <td class="alternate-row1"><input type="radio" name="file_name" value="'. basename($file, '.xml') .'" />'. basename($file, '.xml') .'</td>
                    <td>'. $xml->name .'&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</td>
                    <td class="alternate-row1">'. $xml->lastname .'</td>
                    <td>'. $xml->email .'</td>
                    <td class="alternate-row1">'. $xml->level .'</td>
                    <td>'. $xml->birthday .'</td>
                    <td class="alternate-row1">'. $xml->gender .'</td>
                    <td>'. $xml->age .'</td>
                    <td class="alternate-row1">'. $xml->country .'</td>
                </tr>';
                    }
        ?>
                </table>
            </div>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['file_name'])){
    unlink('users/'.$_POST['file_name']);
}
?>
    <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
    </form>
```

so as you can see i got radio value set has basename (xml file name) but from some reason it not working, any idea why is that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the rendered HTML output? What is the expected one? What is not working? Can you be a bit more clearer?

Comment: The part that doesn't work is the radio value part, i can not delete file by presse delete input button.

Comment: What is the value getting generated?

Comment: What you mean? the loop? it generate name and all that kind of stuff, i create admin panel to delete members so i add details and radio to choose member on the site and just add action like edit or add his level to admin, stuff like that..

Comment: No no... What's getting generated in the `value` attribute of the `<input />` tag?

Comment: Nothing acctualy.. i trying add the basename of it but it doesn't working.

Comment: Try adding the `.xml` extension to the filename in the `unlink`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are going about it in a wrong way.

The PHP is server side, and cannot reach directly to the radio input seeing as it is client side.

What you want requires a two step process: One for getting the page, and one for sending the radio input.

Normally you would use jQuery/AJAX for something like this client side, and isolate the XML related code in a dedicated script server side.

I hope that gets you in the right direction.

Comment: Actually, it is given inside PHP only. Please have a look at it closely.

Comment: Can you help me with this way? i dont know what the way to do that, if i knew the way i wouldn't ask..

Comment: The way i read this, the output would be static page with the correct radio. Which I'm guessing is working. I don't see anything that could possibly delete an XML file? You need another script to handle the values for the radios.